# fabricjs - get real size of an object loaded from JSON

Tags: fabricjs

I'm loading an SVG from a JSON, in a 1500x1500px canvas. Uploading the result of `toSVG()` gets me [this image](https://balibart-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Products/5ab8dae9d5eedc1bd87e7ef5/back/test.svg). As you can see if you inspect the image, the hoodie has a width of 720 px.

Is there a way to get this hoodie's width, even if the JSON wasn't saved using `canvas.toJSON(['width'])` ?

Answer (score 1):

After loading the SVG in canvas you can access the width of it. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/swap123/t57njqh3/13/) is the fiddle of it.

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="1500"></canvas>
```

JS

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('//balibart-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Products/5ab8dae9d5eedc1bd87e7ef5/back/test.svg', function(objects, options) {
      var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
      canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
      displayHoodieWidth();
    });

    let displayHoodieWidth = () => {
        let objects = canvas.getObjects();
      alert(objects[0].width);
    }
```